# How to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have first executed the command: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Then I have opened `.bash_profile` file: `vi ~/.bash_profile`.
In this file, I put:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then if the terminal is closed and restarted, typing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` displays no result.

How to set the path permanently?

Comment: Pointing it out the obvious here... If you just want to fix what you did, add a `$`, e.g. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: just run `sudo ldconfig` after that

Comment: this might be silly but did you `$ source ~/.bash_profile` ? I tend to forget that. And then like @neckTwi said run ldconfig

Answer (score 284):

You should add more details about your distribution, for example under Ubuntu the right way to do this is to add a custom `.conf` file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, for example

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf
```

inside the file you are supposed to write the complete path to the directory that contains all the libraries that you wish to add to the system, for example

```
/home/linux/myLocalLibs
```

remember to add only the path to the dir, not the full path for the file, all the libs inside that path will be automatically indexed.

Save and run `sudo ldconfig` to update the system with this libs.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the distribution. Its Fedora 16

Comment: you can use this solution for Fedora, the solution suggested by  Joachim Pileborg it's useful if you decide to limit the view of this libs to 1 specific user, if you you want a system wide lib tou should use my solution. It all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this really the right way?  Suppose you have multiple users building local libraries, and you've added both of them to /etc/ld.so.conf.d.  Now user A can link to user B's local libraries.  Not good.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` is usually already there, so there's no need to edit any files, just `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Works on xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Strange it worked with all of you guys, however it didn't work for me, while the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ....` way works !!

Comment: This was a lifesaver to resolve this problem:

`'ImportError: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error in SageMaker when trying to import psycopg2.  

Found the path using: 
`$ find ~/ -name libpq.so.5`

Then used @user1824407 suggestion: 
`sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/pyscopg.conf`
followed by SageMaker location for libpg.so.5: 
`/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/`
then ran sudo ldconfig. Magic.

Comment: Man!That saved my life. I tried to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH into environement, .profile, .bashrc ... And the system didn't see the libs.THis one resolved it.Thanks! Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @ergosys it would be better if i could have a ld.so.conf somewhere in my home directory. Is that possible ?

Comment: This didn't work for me, because afterwards, even after rebooting, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty... (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 226):

Keep the previous path, don't overwrite it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/custom/path/
```

You can add it to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/custom/path/' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Don't ask me why, but this did not work, until I made this small change: `mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile` with otherwise the same code and same file privileges. It then worked. This is on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Without this file rename, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would still be empty on re-login. .bashrc was rwx for user, so it should execute fine. Executing it manually would also not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (somewhat expected), and sourcing it (`. ./.bashrc`) did set it. Very odd, and I expect it's Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS specific.

Comment: Adding it to `.bashrc` may make the variable polluted with the value on each new invocation. Consider `~/.bash_profile` , `~/.profile` , or `/etc/profile` instead.

Answer (score 48):

Add

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/you/want1:/path/you/want/2"

to `/etc/environment`

See the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment).

CORRECTION: I should take my own advice and actually read the documentation.  It says that this does not apply to LD_LIBRARY_PATH: *Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files.*  So [user1824407's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428971/4298200) is spot on.

Comment: Wow, I looked at that page several times and overlooked that. Thanks for spotting it and bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Ubuntu is a special case here. Ubuntu's view is that all users want the same libraries and that there is only one place for each library (read discussion in Launchpad bug #366728). However, on multi-user research or development systems, you want each users to be able to have their own versions of libraries. Most Linux distributions allow this and have done so for many years.

Comment: Spent 4 hours trying to figure why I can set PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, but not LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I can't even.

Comment: @JoachimWagner Yes, this is correct, and why conda and/or bioconda or virtenv is now a preferred method on invoking a particular program with special environmental variables.  By using encased environments, inadvertently setting the LD_LIBRARY path will not have systemic issues/problems.

Answer (score 39):

Alternatively you can execute program with specified library dir:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path PATH EXECUTABLE
```

[Read more here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN77).

Comment: Yeah I agree with spt025 - I never knew that trick was possible. I feel there is so much sort of hidden away stored in some archaic manpage at best ... so StackOverflow is really helpful for THAT particular kind of information.

Answer (score 25):

The file `.bash_profile` is only executed by login shells. You may need to put it in `~/.bashrc`, or simply logout and login again.

Comment: Thank you Joachim Pileborg. I have reboot the system and now its path is set permanently.

Answer (score 18):

For some reason no one has mentioned the fact that the bashrc needs to be re-sourced after editing. You can either log out and log back in (like mentioned above) but you can also use the commands: `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 16):

Put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` in `~/.bashrc` [preferably towards end of script to avoid any overrides in between, Default `~/.bashrc` comes with many `if-else` statements]

Post that whenever you open a new terminal/konsole, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will be reflected

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the distribution.
Its Fedora 16

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to the home folder and edit .profile
2. Place the following line at the end

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<your path>`
3. Save and Exit.
4. Execute this command

   `sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 5):

You could try adding a custom script, say  `myenv_vars.sh` in `/etc/profile.d`.

```
cd /etc/profile.d
sudo touch myenv_vars.sh
sudo gedit myenv_vars.sh
```

Add this to the empty file, and save it.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Logout and login, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will have been set permanently.

Comment: Awesome answer. Best choice for me to export a path every time during system initialisation and much safer than physically editing /etc/bashrc

Answer (score 3):

I do the following in Mint 15 through 17, also works on ubuntu server 12.04 and above:

```
sudo vi /etc/bash.bashrc
```

scroll to the bottom, and add:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

All users have the environment variable added.

Answer (score 3):

In **Ubuntu 20.04** Linux this is just not obvious and straight forward as it should be.

I will attempt to make it simple for anyone who is pulling out their hair just like I was with my **Ubuntu 20.04.3 Linux**.

Start by identifying the path where your library files' folder is located. In my case, the ***.so** files that I was working with were located in a folder called **libs** and this folder's path in my Ubuntu box is **/usr/lib**

So now I want to add the path **/usr/lib** to **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** such that when I run **echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH** in my Ubuntu terminal I will be able to see the path  **/usr/lib** echoed as shown below;

```
joseph$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/lib
```

Here are the steps I used

1. Open **terminal** in Ubuntu 20.04 Linux box
2. Change path to **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/** by running **cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/**
3. Create a file with a ***.conf** extension at the end with a **text editor**
   like e.g. **vim** or **gedit** in my case I created it as follows **sudo gedit my_project_libs.conf**
4. Inside the **.conf** file that I created named **my_project_libs.conf**
   I added the path to my libs by adding this line **export
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib**
5. Thereafter, I then run **gedit ~/.bash_profile** to open the
   **~/.bash_profile** file so that I can add inside it this line **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib** which includes the path to the folder with my libraries **/usr/lib** that I want
   included in **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**
6. I also ran **gedit ~/.bashrc** to open the
   **~/.bashrc** file so that I can add inside it this line **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib** which includes the path to the folder with my libraries **/usr/lib** that I want
   included in **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**
7. When you are done adding the line in step 5, **save** and **close**.
8. In your terminal, type the following **sudo ldconfig** and press
   **enter** on your keyboard.
   Close all your open terminals that you were using then open a new terminal session and run echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH If you see the path you added is echoed back, you did it right.

In my case, this is what I see **:/usr/lib** when I run **echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH** in my newly opened Ubuntu terminal session

```
joseph$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/lib
```

That's how I got it to work for me in my **Ubuntu 20.04.3 Linux** box.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be missing the forest for the trees.

The real answer is that '~/.bash_profile' is by default only sourced for LOGIN SHELLS.

The bash config file you are probably looking for if you are starting and closing terminals from your desktop GUI is '~/.bashrc', which is the file sourced by default when starting  interactive, non-login shells.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc