# Why changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect in Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I was trying to deploy my application on `Ubuntu 16.04`. So i made a package with the following hierarchy -

```
Package
|
----bin
    |
    -----application
    -----application.sh
    -----Qt
         |
         -----necessary qt libraries
         -----platforms
```

Here is the `application.sh` file -

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/Qt
./application
```

When i execute the `application.sh` file, it shows me that it cant find the `libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5` file. But its in the `Qt` folder. Also when i print the `ldd application` from the `application.sh` file after exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it gives me following output -

[image] 
Please check the marked parts. Can anyone please explain why the libraries from the `Qt` folder are not found even after exporting the `LD_LIBARRY_PATH`?

**Edit:**

So as suggested by @Zang, i have checked the debug log and here it is -

Please check the marked parts.

[image]

It seems like its actually trying the actual `libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so` and then report that its unable to find it. Can anyone please help me understand whats happening here?

**Edit-2:** As per suggestion from @Tarun, i have ran `ls -al` on my Qt folder. Here is the output -

[image]

Comment: use `export LD_DEBUG=all` enable loader debug output

Comment: @ZangMingJie I have done that and added some info regarding that in Edit. Could you please check?

Comment: Are you mixing 32bit and 64bit builds? Check the so file architecture.

Comment: No, all the libraries and executable are 64 bit binaries.

Comment: Possible that some kind of permission issue? Can you do `ls -al <highlighted path>` and see what happens?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have done that. Please check the edit-2. I am not sure about the result.

Comment: I don't see the actual file there? The soft link points to a file in same folder and I don't see that file

Comment: Yeah got that. Can you add this as an answer so that i can select as a right answer?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov, done added the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the output of your `ls -al`

[image: ls -al output]

These are soft links that you have. Your softlink `libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5` points to `libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.9.2` in the same directory and the file is not there at all. So you need to either set the correct softlink path or have the file in same directory

Answer (score 6):

All files in Your Qt directory are actually simlinks to non-existing files in the same directory, therefore they cannot be found.

Answer (score 5):

**First**

Could it be that the pwd is not where you assume it is?

You could try adding

```
# Figure out where the application.sh script is located
scriptpath="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
# Make sure our pwd is that location
cd  "$scriptpath"
```

in the top of your script (assumes bash shell, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself))

By doing this all relative paths to Qt folder will be valid.

**Second**

Maybe you should considder exporting your new **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, like so (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=whatever
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Third**

It may be useful to run ldconfig command for ld to update after changing the variable (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)):

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so` is not present in `/Desktop/package/bin/Qt` according to the screenshots shown.