# error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, sdl, raspbian

I'm writing a small program using c++. It compiles right, but at execution time it displays this message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've installed this library and I see the file libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0 in folder '/usr/local/lib'

Any idea?

Comment: How are your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings? Also, is `libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0` a link?

Comment: Using "env" coomand I dont't see LD_LIBRARY_PATH values...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux

Comment: Thanks!, great. I've added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib in ~/.bashrc (at the end) and now it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib" in ~/.bashrc (at the end), as suggested here [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux).

Thanks

Comment: But LD is not found inside the local lib folder.. So I am pointing nothing to nothing.

Comment: Seems I am back again searching for the same answer :D