# How to install cjson properly in Ubuntu 14.0LTS?

Tags: c, json, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am new in json and I don't know how to use but I found compare to XML json is better so, I am learning json in C programming in Ubuntu 14.0LTS.

I followed ***https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/install-json-c-in-linux/***. 
In this link, I installed **libjson0** with the help of first command but when I installed **libjson – debug symbols package** with the help of second command which is mentioned in link then showing **"E: Unable to locate package libjson0-dbg"**.

Also I gone through ***https://github.com/json-c/json-c***. After cloning moved to **json-c** directory, in **json-c** directory I did **sh autogen.sh** then showing **"autogen.sh: 2: autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found"**.

Why autoreconf is not works ? When I installed CppUTest and other stuffs then it works.

I also install build-essential which found in google for above problems but it can't works for me.

How can I installed cjson in a proper manner and how to use with the C-programms.

Comment: The tile says cjson, but the content refers to json-c. These are different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Try below commands:

$ sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-0-dev

If you want to debug your programs and see the various steps of serializing/deserializing you can also install the libjson-glib – debug symbols package

$ sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-1.0-0-dbg

For documentation related to json-glib, you must install the following package

$ sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-1.0-0-doc

This documentation will then be available in file:///usr/share/gtk-doc/html/json-glib/index.html

Comment: When I tried for documentation related to json-glib then error occurred "E: Unable to locate package libjson-glib-1.0-0-doc
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libjson-glib-1.0-0-doc' "

Comment: You can download the libjson from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/. After download just unzip it. You will get one PDF document which explains most of the features of this library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related with the path.

The library is installed correctlly but you have tot tell the system where. Here a post on how to do it in Ubuntu [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)