# Not able to install C50 package in R , on linux mint

Tags: r, data-science

i am trying to install C50 package on R but i couldn't : 
install.packages('C50') 
this error appears :[cannot install C50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bemxu.png)
this error : 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas]

Comment: You seem to be missing required system libraries: Lapack and BLAS. (Not really an R problem.) Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676449/lapack-blas-openblas-proper-installation-from-source-replace-system-libraries

Comment: what should i do in this case ?

Comment: I'm not a Linux Mint user so I just retagged and a different set of eyes can take over.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev` should be enougth

Comment: This does make me wonder whether you installed the proper R packages. How long have you been using R? I would have imagined the liblapack should be part of the r-dev package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing these it worked for me : 
 sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
 sudo apt-get install liblapack-doc
 sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
`sudo apt-get install libblas-doc