# Restund giving me error: libre.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, webrtc, centos6

I installed libre 0.4.16 on my server using the following (I did this as `root`):

```
wget http://creytiv.com/pub/re-0.4.16.tar.gz
tar xf re-0.4.16.tar.gz
cd re-0.4.16/
make
make install
```

After that, I went back into the parent folder, and installed restund like so:

```
wget http://creytiv.com/pub/restund-0.4.12.tar.gz
tar xf restund-0.4.12.tar.gz
cd restund-0.4.12/
make
make install
```

After this, I tried running the following in the main folder:

```
restund ./restund-0.4.12/etc/restund.conf
```

And it gave me this error:

```
restund: error while loading shared libraries: libre.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched this up, and I ran `ldconfig` in the main directory, but to no avail.

Any other fixes for this problem? Is it because I'm running it as the `root` user?

I'm running CentOS 6.4 Linux on my server, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think libre installs to /usr/local/lib by default. So you need to add that to your library path or set DESTDIR to /usr/lib/ in the Makefile.

Comment: could you provide more detail? sorry - not very familiar with the Linux environment :)

Comment: I checked, and yes you're right - there's a `libre.so` file inside `/usr/local/lib`. What should I do from here?

Comment: quickest way is to [set LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux). Better yet is to change the system library path as shown (here)[http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/10/how-to-add-shared-libraries-to-linuxs.html]. Or you edit the Makefile and reinstall to /usr/lib. So many choices :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/restund.conf
```

add following line to .conf

```
/usr/local/lib
```

and

```
reload
ldconfig
restart

restund -d /etc/restund.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on your terminal `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it