# R packages: RCurl and curl packages install failure on Linux

Tags: r, linux, curl, rcurl

I hope you can help with this issue I have come across whilst installing RCurl and curl packages for R.

```
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpOBkvFC/R.INSTALLd07e6c06faf4/RCurl/man/url.exists.Rd:5: missing file link ‘file.exists’
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/majaidi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':   
  /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2: symbol krb5int_buf_len, version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/majaidi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in
   ‘/tmp/RtmpX6poG4/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like that you have different versions of `libcurl`. 
One approch could be the following one (for your console):

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_0.9.7.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL curl_0.9.7.tar.gz --no-test-load
ldd /home/majaidi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl/libs/curl.so
```

Then you can use `ldd libcurl.so` to find all dependencies and shared libraries to this. 
Perhaps you can find some errors and/or you have to create a new  [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux).

Good Luck!
J_F

Comment: Thanks for the help. A conflicting version of Kerberos Libraries was creating the issue. Setting up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH has helped get the packages to load successfully (both curl and RCurl)