# Linking with CMakeLists: ld cannot find library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file, with the following:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenNI2)
```

When I run `cmake`, I receive no errors. But when I run `make`, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenNI2
```

However, I have a file called `libOpenNI2.so` in my build directory. So why can `ld` not find this? I thought that the build directory was on the search path for `target_link_libraries`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when linking, the linker doesn't look in the *current* directory but only in a set of predefined directories.

You need to tell CMake *where* the library is, for example by giving the full path to the library in the [`target_link_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command, or [adding it as an imported library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

it works if adding like:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /path_to_library_build/libOpenNI2.a)
```

details:

ld is looking for the libraries in a very short list of folders defined in

```
/etc/ld.so.conf
```

and it usually looks like following:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

and actual paths list from those *.conf files usually is like:

```
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/lib32
/usr/lib32
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

if your project linking library is not in the folder of this list, ld won't find it unless either a special linking variable set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** with the path to your library or a complete path/library name provided in cmake **target_link_libraries** directive.

[details on how to proper setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation? It would help OP and future readers :)

Comment: @Oleg Kokorin Both static and shared versions of a specific library are in the same folder, then which library does Cmake prefer to link to when invoking target_link_libraries(target_name, library_name_without_postfix)?