# C++ Executable Error: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, opc-ua

I have a project path where I have created an executable **testsd**:

```
Caspian@Caspian-VirtualBox:~/TestProject/build/linux/debug/bin/testsd
```

The project directory and heirarchy is as following:

```
/TestProject
|-build/linux/debug/bin
|-ExtLib/folder/lib(containing .a and .so files)
|-ExtLib/folder/src(containing multiple sub folders with .cpp files)
|-ExtLib/folder/include(containing multiple sub folders with .cpp files)
|-src(containing multiple sub folders with .cpp files and mainc.pp)
|-tests(containing Runtests.cpp and catch.hpp files)
```

The problem is when  am running this executable (**./testsd**), I am encountering the following error:

```
./testsd: error while loading shared libraries: libuastackd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The **libuastackd.so** files is contained in ExtLib/folder/lib and ExtLib/folder/src/stack/lib folders. Can anyone help, how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks rG

Answer (score 0):

You might set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment appropriately.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/841108). Read [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html).

<sup>There is some way to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for your entire session, e.g. by editing appropriately `~/.login` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bashenv` or `~/.profile` etc ... and this would alter the behaviour of any program you start after, including some Eclipse IDE</sup>

Read Drepper's [How To Write Shared Libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), notably for other solutions -e.g. appropriate `-Wl,-rpath` settings (which is probably what you really should use).

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Now I have a different senario. I also want to run executable via eclipse IDE, and again the same error shows. How to omit the same error in ecipse?

Comment: Configure your IDE, or your user account (e.g. thru `~/.bashrc` ....) appropriately

Comment: I did not get you properly, can you please elaborate on this?