# Ldd show different version of library on the same c++ executable between different Ubuntu machines

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, ldd

I have created a c++ app that needs libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0  library. In a Ubuntu 16.04 VM I have built the library and the ldd command on my executable gives the following:

```
ldd ./c++_app | grep boost

libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f7a52e62000)
```

Then I zip the app with the relevant shared lib in order to install it on new VM which has not the boost 1.63 library built.
I install the c++ on /usr/bin and the library on a folder lib in /usr/share-data and then update the /etc/ld.so.conf so that it can find the new library
However when I give:

```
 sudo ldconfig -p | grep boost
```

I get

```
 libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/share/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0
```

but when I give ldd on the binary file in /usr/bin I get

```
ldd c++_app | grep boost
libboost_iostreams.so.1.62.0 => not found
```

What I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/share/lib`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux) should help you

Comment: I did it but the same problem which results in error 
"while loading shared libraries: libboost_iostreams.so.1.62.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"  when I try to run my app