# C++ dynamic library dependency troubleshooting

Tags: c++, linux

On Linux OS I have an executable `execA` which has a dynamic library dependency on `libB.so`, and that library has a dynamic library dependency on `libC.so`. The trouble is, on one machine these dependencies work out perfectly fine, but on another machine there is a problem with dependency between `libB.so` and `libC.so` (`libC.so` cannot be found).

Where should I start looking first to resolve this dependency issue?

P.S. An outline of how the dynamic library searches are done would be wonderful.

Comment: Where are all the files located?  Does `libC.so` exist in the search path?

Comment: @Matt What is the 'search' path?

Comment: Look at `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  This may be a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux

Comment: set environnment variable LD_DEBUG before launching execA. LD_DEBUG=libs ./execA

Comment: Use `ldd` to check out the dependencies, i.e. `ldd libB.so`. Do this first on the machine where it works, and compare to the output on the machine where it does not work.