# configure: error: Could not detect the location of the Java shared library. You will need to update java.m4 to add support for this JVM configuration

Tags: java, jvm, scilab

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04

I am installing scilab from the source code as mentioned here : https://wiki.scilab.org/Compilation%20of%20Scilab

I have all the pre-requisites like a C compiler and a Fortran compiler as mentioned here : https://www.scilab.org/download/requirements

But when I enter `./configure` on my terminal, it gives the following error.

```
Looking for JNI libs with x86_64 as machine hardware name
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/jre/lib/x86_64/libjava.so
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/jre/bin/classic/libjvm.so
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/lib/jvm.lib
Looking for /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/jre/lib/mipsel/libjava.so
configure: error: Could not detect the location of the Java
            shared library. You will need to update java.m4
            to add support for this JVM configuration.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHXXS.png)

I have already tried to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux following this answer : [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)
as I had read that this might solve the issue[(here)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/scilab-scicos-installation-704736/). Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall OpenJDK or OracleJDK.
This might help:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```