# How do I call a Java Native Interface C function from my Go code?

Tags: c, go, java-native-interface, cgo, javah

I am up with implementing my Java Native Interface functions in Golang using the golang `C` lib. 
Now I want to convert a `jstring` to an UTF-8 string using the JNI function `GetStringUTFChars` but I get an error when doing it. These are the steps I have done:

In my Java class (called MyClass) where I have defined the JNI method, I have:

```
public static native void print(String msg);
```

Using `javah`, I have generated the `.h`-file with the function defined in C language:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_print
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);
```

Then, in my Go code I have the following code:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin
/*
#include <jni.h>
*/
import "C"

//export Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_print
func Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_print(env *C.JNIEnv, clazz C.jclass, str C.jstring) {

    _ = C.GetStringUTFChars(env, str, 0)

}
```

When I build the `go` file using:
`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libmyclass.dylib libmyclass.go` 
then I get the following error:

`could not determine kind of name for C.GetStringUTFChars`

How should I call the `GetStringUTFChars` defined in the [JNI spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) so I then can print the string with `fmt.println`?

**EDIT 2**
Removed "edit 1" since the procedure above was correct, it was just the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable that was not set.

Comment: As far as I know, CGO doesn't support calling through C function pointers. So you'd have to write a small wrapper library in C with functions that take a `JNIEnv*` and then calls `*(env)->TheActualJniFunction(env, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI functions like `GetStringUTFChars` are function pointers and cannot be called directly from Go. You have to wrap the functions you need in a separate C file. e.g.

*jx.c*

```
#include <jni.h>

const char* jx_GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring str, jboolean *isCopy) {
    return (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, isCopy);
}
```

After creating a library from the C file, your Go file will look something like this:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/include/linux/
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/ -ljx

#include "jx.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

//export Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_print
func Java_com_mypackage_MyClass_print(env *C.JNIEnv, clazz C.jclass, str C.jstring) {
    s := C.jx_GetStringUTFChars(env, str, (*C.jboolean)(nil))
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(s))
}

func main() {}
```

The reason why there is a separate C file just for the wrapper function is because of this clause in the documentation:

> Using //export in a file places a restriction on the preamble: since it is copied into two different C output files, it must not contain any definitions, only declarations.

Comment: Thanks! So the steps I need to to is first build a shared library of jx.c using `gcc -shared -fPIC -I/.../libjx.so` and then point to that shared library using LDFLAGS in the Go file? Correct? I have tried that and it compiles when I do `go build...` but when running my Java program that uses my JNI method, then I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/rox/jnijava/target/libjnijava.so: libjx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` but both libjnijava.so (created by go build) and libjx.so (created by gcc -shared...) exist on that path.

Comment: Yes, build the C file first and then you can create a library using `ar q libjx.a jx.c`. Then build your go shared object, e.g. `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o gox.so so.go`. You might need to add `libjx.so` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux

Comment: Please have a look at my edit above where I added the steps to reproduce the error on Linux with Java 11. I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point at the folder with the shared objects. I have also tried with setting the Java option `-Djava.library.path` but with no luck. So I am still stuck :-(

Comment: This: `/home/rox/gojni/target/libgojni.so` is not = to this: `/home/rox/jnijava/target/libjnijava.so`.

Comment: Thanks! I was testing with some different projects on different platforms and copy-pasted from wrong project. :-)
Got it working now though. It turned out that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH wasn´t set for the session I used.