# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found required by TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, debian, libstdc++

I'm trying to deploy a **flask** app on a **debian** server using Machine Learning libs, i managed that so far with most ML libraries but i got this error thanks to **TensorFlow** which i researched a lot about it with no working solution for me.

PS : I'm using a 3.7 python venv for my app

> ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /flask/wstest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
>   Mar 01 15:32:11 django gunicorn[8803]: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

I'm clearly missing the GLIBCXX **3.4.21** because `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`shows **3.4.20** as the latest version.

Tried this fix `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
Gives this : 
[result of the toolchain add attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZR1u.png)

Tried apt-get update, Got this

> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Also tried to update libgcc and libstdc++6, says i have the latest version.

EDIT : I'm suspecting that Debian 8 Jessie doesn't support a higher glibcxx version than the 3.4.20.

Comment: Are you using TF 1.13.1?

Comment: I tried TF 1.13.1 and 1.13.0, couldn't install older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i just tested **Stretch** and it works fine. The issue is related to the OS in this case **Debian 8 Jessie** , it cannot handle a higher version of glibcxxx than the 3.4.20.

**PS** : **Stretch** is **Debian 9**'s distribution name

Answer (score 24):

Here's a solution for this problem in Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

You can check if you get GLIBCXX desired version like this:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It is general, is easy to understand and the `strings` command is a great way to test to see if your problem is the same and also to see if the it has correctly changed after running the `apt` commands. 

FYI, I am Ubuntu 20 and `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9` did not work but it was still able to correctly upgrade `libstdc++`. 

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain *WHY* upgrading `libstdc++6` does the trick? I would expect the symbols to be consistent within a given package

Comment: Also *WHY* to we need to add `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`? The name sounds experimental, and it feels odd to require an external repository for something as standard as `libstdc`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Anaconda/Miniconda, you can also get your OS to use the `libstdc++.so.6` provided with your installation by setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  Say you have Miniconda installed in `/home/whatever/miniconda3` and you're using `bash`.  Then add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/whatever/miniconda3/lib
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/whatever/miniconda3/lib
```

`source ~/.bashrc` or restart your shell and you should be good to go.

See also: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and [How to update libstdc++.so.6 or change the file to use on Tensorflow, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921248/how-to-update-libstdc-so-6-or-change-the-file-to-use-on-tensorflow-python) .

Comment: This answer helped to solve my problem. However, I believe the way the LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be exported is like this: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:...` like shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37558191/8488985)

Comment: did not change anything... error persists