# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, importerror, glibc, libstdc++

I'm getting this error while running my python script on a Linux virtual machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "model.py", 
line 7, in <module>     from data_load import *   File "/home/oshanjayawardanav100/biometrics-self-supervised/supervised_ucihar/data_load.py", 
line 2, in <module>     from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", 
line 82, in <module>     from .base import clone   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", 
line 17, in <module>     from .utils import _IS_32BIT   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", 
line 28, in <module>     from .fixes import np_version, parse_version   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", 
line 20, in <module>     import scipy.stats   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", 
line 441, in <module>     from .stats import *   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", 
line 43, in <module>     from . import distributions   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", 
line 8, in <module>     from ._distn_infrastructure import (rv_discrete, rv_continuous, rv_frozen)   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", 
line 24, in <module>     from scipy import optimize   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", 
line 400, in <module>     from .optimize import *   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", 
line 36, in <module>     from ._numdiff import approx_derivative   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_numdiff.py", 
line 8, in <module>     from ._group_columns import group_dense, group_sparse 
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)`
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this.

I already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55899959/15938633
But it is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ref. "I already tried this" : The link is about Debian 8. ..... Please add OS name and version to your question. ( There is a solution, also for old Debian 8, e.g. `libstdc++.so.6.0.29` )

Comment: Try your code after reinstalling `sklearn` library on your `debian` system by using sklearn debian version python3. [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#debian-ubuntu](reference link to follow). This could be the reason to error of you getting; package wheel related not found under python3 directory.