# `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, importerror, tensorflow-lite

hi tried to make a code for detecting objects with coco followed this guide:
[guide](https://www.digikey.ca/en/maker/projects/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-tensorflow-lite-on-raspberry-pi/b929e1519c7c43d5b2c6f89984883588)
i am using rpi3B+
tried to use other suggestions online but that didnt work.
when trying to run the code at the last part of the guide, i got an import error and as mentioned above the error in the title.
the full **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adls3x/Projects/Python/tflite/object_detection/TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 88, in <module>
    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
  File "/home/adls3x/Projects/Python/tflite/tflite-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tflite_runtime import _pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper as _interpreter_wrapper
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/adls3x/Projects/Python/tflite/tflite-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_runtime/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.so)
```

lines 87-94 in my **code**: (error in second line of the code ahead)

```
if pkg:
    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
else:
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate
```

please note the folders in the error while helping me because i am very bad at improvising tech stuff.

if needed any more information please tell me
any help will be appreciated

i have tried upgrading tensorrflow, uninstalling and installing, trying another rpi. nothing is working :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/lib/x86\_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.21' not found required by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948216/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found-req)

Comment: tried to but raised an error in this line : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

raise this:

Comment: self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/bullseye