# How can I fix a 'tcc: library not found' error?

Tags: c, linker-errors, cs50, tcc

I am taking CS50, and since I am now using linux, I was hoping that I could do my coding for the CS50 problem sets on my local computer, instead of on the cloud9 ide. So I cloned the CS50 library from [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50) and installed it, but when I try to compile my code with tcc like this:

```
tcc -lcs50 tideman.c
```

I get this error:

```
tcc: error: library 'cs50' not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try `tcc tideman.c -lcs50`?

Comment: also, you need to ensure that you update the library path on your system.

Comment: You first suggestion yields the same result. How would I update the library path?

Comment: maybe see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/2173917)?

Comment: Even after updating the library path like that I still get the same thing.

Comment: Is the library located in the path you specified? Did you check after installing the lib?

Comment: Yes it is, in /usr/local/lib