# How to include all .so libraries across subdirectories

Tags: ubuntu, conan, .so

I have a bunch of .so libraries and I would like to include them similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux) (Ubuntu 18.04).

I have followed the steps from the most upvoted answer from user1824407

I created `.conf` file

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/so_libraries.conf
```

And then I started adding the .so libraries into the file like this:

```
/home/developer/.conan/.../lib
```

But it is very clumsy, in the /.conan/ directory there is a lot of subdirectories with the .so libraries. Is there any way to automatically include all the .sos in the .conan directory? Writing just `/home/developer/.conan` does not work.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find:

```
 find /home/developer/.conan -name "*.so" -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/so_libraries.conf
```

Find all the files with .so extensions in the directory/child directories and print only the leading directories (%h) and not the file names. Pipe through to sort and uniq to remove duplicates and output the results to the config file.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be helpful, however, unfortunately, it does not work, because (i suppose it is necessary to write it into cmd) when I tried to pass the command (both with and without sudo at the beginning)  `bash: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/so_libraries.conf: Permission denied` (even though I do have admin rights at my Ubuntu) Thank you

Comment: Try with sudo bash -c 'find /home/developer/.conan -name "*.so" -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/so_libraries.conf'

Comment: That solved the problem, once again thank you very much