# simple quest about LD_LIBRARY_PATH and new entries

Tags: linux, python-2.7, numpy, environment-variables

In Ubuntu 16, when setting environment variable like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux), what we had in LD_LIBRARY_PATH before will be erased? I have already ROS and want to add the [opencv<->numpy converter](https://github.com/GarrickLin/numpy-opencv-converter). I don't want to lose what I already have in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, though and everywhere I search I don't find if it edits what we have in env variable or just add new entries. Don't want to lose anything haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about how ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} is used like this:

```
$ man ld.so
```

You already know that ${PATH} is a list of directories that are polled when just an application name is given:

```
$ foo
```

and ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} works exactly the same for the ld.so(1) dynamic library linker.

The tricky bit is that ld.so(1) uses a cache of the shared libraries found the last time the ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} was used.  This speeds up the program starting, just as any cache is supposed to do.  Lots of examples show just mentioning a single directory to pick up an application-specific library:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/wonderful/library
$ foo
```

but that is depending that the existing cache already any other needed library because the ld.so(1) will know to search only that "/my/wonderful/library/" location.

A better solution is to add the new directory like this:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/wonderful/library:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
$ foo
```

which will work even if the ld.so(1) cache gets deleted out from under you and ldconfig(1) has to rebuild that cache.

This idiom that exports the ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} permanently is a bad, bad idea:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/wonderful/library:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
$ foo
```

because the custom ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} will be used for the "foo" application plus *any child program in this process tree*.  Instead, always limit the setting to process tree here instead of anything run from this shell ever again.  Keep control of where the path is set like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/wonderful/library:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} foo
```

limits visibility of the ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} to only "foo" and any process it spawns.

Comment: so.. it's bad that I did `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/module/i/am/trying/to/import` .. cause I couldn't make the module work doing this nor could find the damn `np_opencv_converter.so` that is required to run the module

Comment: oh, and what's the difference between the order : `LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/directory/of /module`  or `/directory/of/module:LD_LIBRARY_PATH`