# Is it possible to modify Poetry's activate script to add path to Ghostscript?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-poetry

After installing the Ghostscript dependency for Camelot (which is not installed automatically by Poetry when installing camelot-py), when running my app Camelot could not find Ghostscript even though it was installed. Following [Need to install Ghostscript to Mac PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391805/need-to-install-ghostscript-to-mac-path) answer by Mark Setchell and adding the location of Ghostcript to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, it worked! However I have to add it every time I activate the virtual environment (poetry shell). Is there a way to configure it so this path is added automatically when activating? I found the location of the environment through poetry env info however I can't figure out where to add the export path command or whether it would even work.

Tried this and it works: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:
Can this be added somewhere in Poetry's virtual environment activation script to get it to run every time?