# How to add a path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: ubuntu, netcdf4

I'm trying to install NetCDF in Ubuntu, so I followed the guide in: https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/nug/current/getting_and_building_netcdf.html

but when I get to the actual building I get the error of "can't find or link to the hdf5 library" even tho I already installed it. The solution seems to be in the guide:

*"Before building netCDF, you may need to add ${H5DIR}/lib to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable if that lib directory is not searched by default" *

So the question is: how to do that? what's the code?

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives me a path to ~/netcdf-c.-4.9.2/lib but no idea where it should be pointing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the environmental variable LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)

Comment: No, I had already read it but tried this and now my path is: /home/username/netcdf-c-4.9.2/lib::/home/username/hdfs5-1.12.2/lib yet the netcdf keeps giving the same hdf5 error

Comment: This might be (might because i do not know if it's about the sameversion) related:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383995/error-cant-find-of-link-to-hdf5-libary-while-installing-netcdf-4