error while loading shared libraries: libpqxx-6.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
After building the code when run the executable I get error
./test_pq: error while loading shared libraries: libpqxx-6.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Example of my CMake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_library(pqxx libpqxx.so PATHS  "/opt/bb/lib64")
find_library(pq libpq.so PATHS  "/opt/bb/lib64")

if(EXISTS ${pqxx})
    message(STATUS "found Path ${pqxx}")
endif()

add_executable(test_pq test_pq.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_pq
PUBLIC
    "/opt/bb/include/pqxx6"
)

target_compile_options(test_pqa
PUBLIC
    -std=c++17
    -pthread
    
)
target_link_options(test_pq
PUBLIC
    -L/opt/bb/lib64
)
target_link_libraries(test_pq
PUBLIC 
    pqxx
    pq
)

C++ code:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    try
    {
        pqxx::connection connectionObject("host=test port=10991 dbname=test user=test password=test");
        pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);

        if (connectionObject.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Opened database successfully: " << connectionObject.dbname() << "\n";
            try {
                pqxx::result response = worker.exec("select * from employee");
                std::cout << response.size() << "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << "ID: " << response[i][0].c_str() << " Name: " << response[i][2].c_str() << "\n";
                }
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't open database" << "\n";
            return 1;
        }
       // C.disconnect();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}



I am ding simple cmake .. and make VERBOSE=1. Its building and Linking and all looks good:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-12/root/usr/bin/c++ -L/opt/bb/lib64 CMakeFiles/ball_init.dir/ball_init.cpp.o -o ball_init  -lpqxx -lpq

Not sure what am I missing here.

So does that file libpqxx-6.2.so exist? Did you check your filesystem? If this is a link make sure that the link is valid.

I am confused at the question. Do you get an error while building or running? If your problem is running the executable maybe you need to add the location of the .so to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environment-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux

I don't see this file in my existing installation
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 bpkg bpkg   16 Aug 10 03:33 libpqxx.so -> libpqxx.so.6.2.3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 bpkg bpkg   16 Aug 10 03:33 libpqxx.so.6 -> libpqxx.so.6.2.3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 bpkg bpkg   98 Oct  8 03:03 libpqxx.so.6.2.3
that's why i am wondering why i am getting this error

I don't get any error while building. I am getting this error while trying to execute. I did setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH but I don't see libpqxx-6.2.so in my lib I have 6.2.3 version installed. is there a way to setup the specific version

What is output of ldd test_pq when you run it from the directory with your executable?

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcdf79f000)
libpqxx-6.2.so => not found
libpq.so.5 => /opt/bb/lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fa7321c0000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa731d01000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa7319ff000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa7317e9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa73141b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa7311ff000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /opt/bb/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fa73212a000)

Not sure why this looking for libpqxx-6.2.so when I am specifying in find_library(pqxx libpqxx.so PATHS  "/opt/bb/lib64") look for libpqxx.so

It looks like your libpqxx.so.6.2.3 library has SONAME libpqxx-6.2.so, which doesn't look correct (see e.g. that question about the way for check the SONAME). What is origin of libpqxx.so and related files which you have put under /opt/bb/lib64? Probably, those files have been built incorrectly.

yes you are wright libpqxx.so.6.2.3 library has SONAME libpqxx-6.2.so. Looks Like i have to contact the package owner who is building this package. Thank you.
